# macbook m1: error Failed to launch emulator

Tags: react-native, sdk, android-emulator, apple-m1

I use macbook m1 and set sdk in android studio.
I follow all the process: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

[image]

But I couldn't understand above process.
when I run this command line from terminal. It says

> zsh: command not found: sdkmanager

So I pass that process.

Except for that, I installed all as doc says.
But when I run `npx react-native run-android`.

Error message below appears.
what is the problem?

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/hayat/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/hayat/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (/Users/hayat/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/hayat/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/hayat/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/hayat/Documents/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running android emulator on m1 chip requires extra installation steps.

I recommend you to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjUCXGGJu7E&ab_channel=AlexZiskind) which might be helpful to your situation.

[See this also.](https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases)