# Can't Run adb On M1 zsh: segmentation fault adb

Tags: react-native, android-studio, segmentation-fault, adb, apple-m1

I try to run my **React Native** project on **MacBook Pro M1** but when I run **adb** it's gives error : **zsh: segmentation fault adb**.

I tried run **adb** from both `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` & `~/usr/local/bin/adb`.

Tried reinstall platform-tools in android studio.

Tried install and reinstall platform-tools from brew.

Tried reinstall android studio itself.

**Device: MacBook Pro M1 2020, SSD: 512, RAM: 8**

**OS: macOS Monterey**

**Android Studio: android-studio-2021.1.1.21-mac_arm**

Comment: I'm seeing the same issues since upgrading to build-tools 32.0.0. Google states "Known issue: this version crashes when run without any arguments."

Comment: yes it is. I explained for the error which I had, hop it can helps you too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After install **Android Studio** create ready project using android studio's ready templates, then **build** the project. You will get error, **ignore** the error.

go to **sdk manager** then remove **platform-tools** and click **apply** button then click **Ok** and restart android studio.

again go to **sdk manager** then install **platform-tools**.
go to the project and **build** it, build should be **successful**.
run the project.

Now go to your **React Native** project and run for android. BOOM it up.

For **physical device** tests copy your final **gradle** to android studio and run it from android studio itself.

The `zsh: segmentation fault adb` still remains but you can run you're project on android emulator.

Google Says: "Pending and it will be ok at the next update"

Answer (score 9):

adb gives error but adb command works

[image]

Comment: adb
[1]    85820 segmentation fault  adb


adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 32.0.0-8006631


Interesting, adb crashes but adding params make it work.

Comment: Tnx to you, latest update solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Android SDK Platform-Tools solved the issue for me. Go to Android Studio > Settings > System Settings > Android SDK.

- Click SDK Tools tab. Uncheck Android SDK Platform-Tools from the list. Click Apply to uninstall the package.
- Check Android SDK Platform-Tools and click Apply to reinstall it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70860342/9631529) looks similar to your problem. Setting up android emulators on mac m1 pros requires extra installation steps.

Comment: It doesn't related to my problem. Thanks for answer.