# Cannot launch Android Emulator on Macbook m1 2020

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator, qemu, apple-silicon

I am unable to launch android emulator on my macbook m1. Sometimes an error is displayed without the mac restarting and sometimes a pink screen is displayed for less than a second and mac restarts. I was using macOs BigSur previously and I am now on MacOs Ventura 13.2.1, but the problem has persisted regardless of the OS.
I have tried running android emulator using android studio as well as the m1 preview (https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases). I tried almost everything I could search and find, some of them include:

1. Updating android studio multiple times (Currently on Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2)
2. Changed from zulu jdk to java open jdk
3. https://www.arthurkoziel.com/qemu-on-macos-big-sur/ (qemu installed using homebrew)
4. [Android emulator doesn't work on Apple M1 chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65016541/android-emulator-doesnt-work-on-apple-m1-chip)
5. [Android Emulator stop working after update to 31.2.6 [M1/Apple Silicon]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876404/android-emulator-stop-working-after-update-to-31-2-6-m1-apple-silicon#)
6. [Android Studio/Emulator on macOS with ARM CPU M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1)
7. [macbook m1: error Failed to launch emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859947/macbook-m1-error-failed-to-launch-emulator)
8. Updated contents on Android studio > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System settings > Android sdk > SDK Tools (Android emulator - 32.1.14, Android sdk platform tools - 34.0.3)

   This doc contains the error logs for various cases: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ssCN9tKIfHnmdGHLbmAlMBbeAPiMVbDwzZhPWhf4wvU/edit?usp=sharing

   If anyone has faced a similar issue or has any insights on the matter, please help.

Answer (score 0):

that's my settings for running a simple device on my m1:

- IDE

  - Android studio flamingo 2022.2.1 patch2
  - Android SDK build-tools 34
  - Android emulator 32.1.14
  - Android SDK platform tools 34.0.3
- VIRTUAL DEVICE

  - Name: Pixel2 API 26
  - Display: Pixel2 (with play store) 5.0", 1080x1920, 420dpi
  - Image: Pie, api 28, arm64-v8a, android 9.0 AOSP (it hasn't the google apis)
  - Graphics: automatic
  - RAM: 2048MB
  - VM heap: 2048MB

I hope this can help!

Comment: Hello @simonecocco, thanks for the comment. I will try out your settings and see if I can get it running.

Comment: I used the same configurations as you mentioned, but no luck. I get the error 'The emulator process for AVD <device-name> has terminated' or mac restarts sometimes.

Comment: @Subash How much RAM does your Mac have?

Comment: I have 8 GB ram

Comment: Ok, I think that can be the problem (I have 16GB of RAM). Imo reducing VM RAM to 1GB and VM head to 0.5GB could help. Anyway try to open only device manager from android studio splash screen and boot your VM without any other app open.

Comment: Ok, I will try it that way. Thanks for the response.